# Querying for dates in doctrine

Tags: date, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-2.1

I have a table called `active_plans` in which there are two columns: `activated_date` and `last_billed_at`. Basically, I want to create a query that looks at these two columns like this:

```
select all from active_plans 
          where last_billed_at = null AND activated_date + 1 month = today, 
          or if last_billed_at + 1 month = today.
```

I can't seem to figure out how to do this, though.

Comment: If it helps, both columns are datetime format.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM active_device_plans
                    WHERE (last_billed_at = NULL AND DATE(activation_date) = DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH)))
                    OR (DATE(last_billed_at) = DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH)))` isn't working, using Doctrine's createNativeQuery... I'm not sure how else to approach this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up doing something a lot different:
    public function getBillToday()
    {
        $activePlans = $this->entityManager
                ->createQuery('SELECT adp FROM adp
                    WHERE adp.activationDate IS NOT NULL')
                ->getResult();
        $data = array();

```
    foreach ($activePlans as $plan) {
        $recur = $plan->getPlan()->getRecurringInMonths();
        $nextBillTime = strtotime('-'.$recur.' months', time());
        $nextBill = date('Y-m-d', $nextBillTime);
        $activationDate = $plan->getActivationDate();
        $lastBilledAt = $plan->getLastBilledAt() != NULL ? $plan->getLastBilledAt()->format('Y-m-d') : 0;
        if ($activationDate == $nextBill || $lastBilledAt == $nextBill) {
            $data[] = $plan->getId();
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
```